# Adding 'Open Sans' to PDF engine

Tags: r

I need to add OpenSans (can be obtained from [here](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans)) to pdf engine.

After adding downloaded fonts to system I do as specified on [this page](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/09/09/preparing-figures-for-plos-one-with-r/): first `font_import()`, then I see my fonts in output of `fonts()` and then I do `loadfonts()`.

But after that all `pdf(family="Open Sans")` ouputs

```
Error in pdf(family = "Open Sans")  : 
  unknown family 'Open Sans'
```

How can I fix the problem?

**UPD.**  I've found `More than one version of regular/bold/italic found for Open Sans. Skipping setup for this font` in output of `loadfonts()`

Comment: What’s the output of `names(pdfFonts())`? I’m guessing `Open Sans` is not in there, which means it wasn’t installed as a *PDF* font, or it was installed under a different name.

Comment: yes, there's `Open Sans` in `fonts()` and it's missing in `names(pdfFonts())`. How can I install it as PDF font?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I've found `More than one version of regular/bold/italic found for Open Sans. Skipping setup for this font.` in output of `loadfonts()`. How can that be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

As it was noted in question `loadfonts` located several versions of `Open Sans` and due to that `loadfonts` worked incorrectly.

The problem was solved by...

1. Removed `Open Sans` font from system (from `C:\Windows\Fonts` in my case) and reinstalled it from link above.
2. Found `fonttable.csv` in `c:\Users\[Username]` folder and removed one line with "Open Sans" from there.
3. Called `loadfonts` again